# CSS Unable to use hover effect on list ID item

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a Navbar that has a `<li>` and one of those list items have a ID of **Navbar-login-btn**. I am able to modify just that ID in the css, however whenever I try to use the **:hover** function on it; it does not work.

Is there something I am doing wrong here, because I am not sure. Any help would be nice, thank you!

**Navbar.jsx:**

```
import '../App.css';
import myAvatar from '../images/avataaars.png'

function Navbar() {
    return(
        <div className='Navbar-container'>
            <img src={myAvatar} className='Nav-logo'/>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Skills</li>
                <li>Projects</li>
                <li id='Navbar-login-btn'>Login</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Navbar;
```

**App.css:**

```
.Navbar-container{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
}

.Nav-logo {
    width: 75px;
    height: auto;
}

#Navbar-login-btn {
    border: 2px solid rgb(101, 201, 255);
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: rgb(101, 201, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
}

#Navbar-login-btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(101, 201, 255);
}

.Navbar-container ul{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    font-family: Russo One;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 40px;
}

.Navbar-container li{
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: When you inspect the item menu does it have the ID present and in the CSS properties the hover defined?

Comment: Yes it is, however I do not see :hover in there

Answer (score 0):

You have same background-color on `#Navbar-login-btn` & `#Navbar-login-btn:hover`

Try replacing different color on one of them

Example:

```
#Navbar-login-btn:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgb(15 98 143);//place this new color
}
```

Playcode: Sample result [here](https://playcode.io/1014671)

Comment: That does not seem to work either. Whenever I hover over it, nothing happens.

Comment: Did you open the sample result on my answer? Try to hover on the Login , you will see it changes the color. Or do  you want to hover all the list on your navbar ?

Comment: I did open it, and it works in your demo. However it does not work in my actual page.

Comment: It's almost like my page does not recongize the :hover

Comment: Can you paste your updated version on the playcode and share the link here?

Comment: I actually figured out I needed to define a z-index for the page.

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend you use a `kebab-case` for the CSS property.

example - `navbar-container`. lowercase with a hyphen.

By the way, you don't have to use an ID to grab the element you want.
you can use [last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) method.

In your case:

If the `Login` is the last Element in the list. use this:

```
// for the navbar
.navbar-container{
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px 40px 10px 40px;
}
// for ul in the navbar
.navbar-container ul{
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    font-family: Russo One;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 40px;
}
// for li ul in the navbar
.navbar-container ul li{
    padding: 10px;
}
// for last li ul in the navbar
.navbar-container ul li:last-child {
    border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

Comment: That does work, however when I got to hover over it; nothing happens.

Comment: ok. so try this.
1. Open up Developer Tools and go to Sources.
Note the shortcut to pause script execution—F8.

2.Pause script execution

3. Interact with the UI to get the element to appear.

4. Hit F8.
5. Now you can move your mouse around, inspect the DOM, whatever. The element will stay there.